# Unicode - the right thing to do

Tags: utf-8

I'm working on something which processes `UTF-8` encoding, and I found myself asking the question:

- What should I do when I encounter a byte which never occur inside a
  `UTF-8` encoded string?

i.e. `0x1111111X`

For example, I'm writing a small snippet of code which looks at the current place in the stream of bytes, and tells you how many bytes are used to represent the code point at that place in the stream.

- `0x0XXXXXXX` just 1
- `0x10XXXXXX` oops, we are in a continuation byte,
  search back upstream to find the leading byte
- `0x11XXXXXX` count the
  number of leading 1s, that's the answer
- `0x1111111X` err, this is not
  possible in `UTF-8`!!! what to do!?!?

I'm thinking of returning an error value, but wondering if I should, as a side effect, replace it with some more predictable error glyph (I mean the code point representing said glyph). And later when I do something more complicated, like jumping through the string and find that the leading byte does not have the correct number of continuation bytes after it... I'm thinking I should "fix" that up too.

Is it standard practice to leave wrongly encoded strings broken, or to change them and make them be wrong but at least play nice?

Comment: I think about browsers. If you set encoding utf-8 and use non-utf-8 characters, then they appear like question mark in a rhombus. So I think you can change wrong characters. But if you send or store this data then obviously you have to store a copy from the original.

Comment: @qben Yes, I did think about this, but see, that could just be the display code or some underlying processing lib. I guess my question is just about the lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way is to just throw a meaningful error if the input is not correct and stop.

There are a lot of good reasons to do so:

- speed: if you try to fix errors this often cause your 
  function to be slower even on correct inputs
- simplicity: your code can become really complicated if you try to fix any error
- maintainability and correctness: it's just easier to ensure the function works correctly 
  when you stop whenever the input does not match the specification you are working with. Since you have only to check input according to specification.
- purpose: any time you get to such a point like here you have to think about: 
  what is the purpose of my function? Why I came up with the idea to write it?

  Also: a function **fixcode** which fixes the uft8 could be used also at an other place, so it makes total sense to separate fixing (purpose, simplicity, maintainability and correctness argument again).

  Even if you expect an error, I would prefer to separate the encode and **fixcode** since
  your can reuse **fixcode** in outer contexts.

If you are really thinking about fixing the utf8 code while encoding I would use a pattern like this:

```
try {
  q = encode(s);
} catch(encodingerror) {
  log(encodingerror);
  t = fixcode(s);
  q = encode(t);
}
```

Comment: I would rather not have that exception pattern mentioned, it seems like a bad use of exceptions and I can think of a few simpler ways to implement off the top of my head. Good points though, especially about separation of responsibility for reuse/maintenance.